# Solving of algebra of the picture

Tags: math

i saw this picture over social network

[image]

put into equation that will be:

Given:

```
A=rabit
B=Dog
C=Cat

    A+C=10
    A+B=20
    C+B=24
```

solve A+B+C = ?

some programming logic? what is your answer?

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For goodness sake, this is little more than a high school algebra word problem in pictures.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about high school algebra, not programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any programming logic in this, its just Math.

B + C = 24
-A-C = -20

Adding these two,

B-A = 4

Now taking the 1st equation,

A+B = 10
-A+B = 4

Adding both again

2B= 14

**B = 7
Then, A = 3 ( from A+B = 10) and C = 17kgs (from B + C = 24)**

Comment: I prefer to add all three pictures together, and note that you've included everyone twice. So the answer is (10+20+24)/2 - no need to calculate their individual weights.

Comment: Oh yes, that would certainly be the simplest method. I missed that the combined weight is what is required. Thanks for the correction!